# Mann–Whitney U test on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a large dataframe similar to this one:

```py
In [1]: grades
Out[1]: 
                          course1  course2
school  class  student                    
school1 class1 student1         2        2
               student2         3        2
               student3         1        3
               student4         3        1
               student5         3        1
...                           ...      ...
        class3 student86        3        1
               student87        2        2
               student88        1        1
               student89        3        3
               student90        0        1

[90 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to compute the Mann-Whitney rank test on the grades from the sample school and each sub-sample class. How can I do this using pandas and [scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) without iterating through the dataframe?

Comment: To clarify, I want to compute the mannwhitneyu using each class and its school. E.g:
mannwhitneyu(class1, school1), mannwhitneyu(class2,school1) etc

Comment: The Mann-Whitney U *of what* on each class and its school?  What values do you want to compare with Mann-Whitney U?  The values of course1 for a given class and school?  The values of course2 for a given class and school?  Something else?  Also, I wouldn't recommend comparing a class with its school, since then the two groups will not be independent (because the class data is part of the school data).

Comment: Yes, that was what I was planning to do. However, I know realize it is not the correct way to do it since they are not independent. Your answer give me a better understanding how to use pandas groupby and apply. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is `groupby` on the index levels and apply a function that calls `mannwhitneyu`, passing the two columns `course1` and `course2`.  Suppose this is your data:

```
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['school{0}'.format(n) for n in xrange(3)],
    ['class{0}'.format(n) for n in xrange(3)],
    ['student{0}'.format(n) for n in xrange(10)]
])
d = pandas.DataFrame({'course1': np.random.randint(0, 10, 90), 'course2': np.random.randint(0, 10, 90)},
                     index=index)
```

Then to compute Mann-Whitney U by school:

```
>>> d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda t: stats.mannwhitneyu(t.course1, t.course2))
school0    (426.5, 0.365937834646)
school1    (445.0, 0.473277409673)
school2    (421.0, 0.335714211748)
dtype: object
```

And to do it by class:

```
>>> d.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda t: stats.mannwhitneyu(t.course1, t.course2))
school0  class0     (38.5, 0.200247279189)
         class1     (37.0, 0.169040187814)
         class2     (46.5, 0.409559639829)
school1  class0     (33.5, 0.110329749527)
         class1     (47.5, 0.439276896563)
         class2    (30.0, 0.0684355963119)
school2  class0     (47.5, 0.439438219083)
         class1     (43.0, 0.308851989782)
         class2     (34.0, 0.118791221444)
dtype: object
```

The numbers in the `levels` argument to `groupby` refer to the levels of your MultiIndex.  So grouping by level 0 groups by school and grouping by levels 0 and 1 groups by school/class combination.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to do something like stats.mannwhitneyu(class0, school0) etc? Can I access the different levels in the aggfunc?